# highstock: space between opposite x-axis and range-selector/datepicker

Tags: padding, axis, highcharts, space

I have an opposite x-axis above the chart. However, I don't know how I may put additional space between those a-axis values (Monday, Tuesday etc) and the fixed range selector + datepicker horizontal menu?

Does anybody got an idea?

Comment: Could you add simple jsFiddle demo with that issue?

Answer (score 0):

yes, sure.

//jsfiddle.net/V92vr/

you can see that the opposite xaxis overlap with the range selector...how can I add here more space?

Answer (score 0):

Reported in related topic, here:

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3013#issuecomment-42282709